# What is class static variable in java

Tags: java, class, oop

Where is class static field is declared and how this field is associated with every classes?

```
System.out.pritnln(String.class);
System.out.pritnln(Student.class);
```

output:

```
class java.lang.String
class Student
```

Comment: This is implemented by the JRE (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2).

Comment: I just flagged this question as unclear, because... I really don't get it.

Comment: Thank you @OliverCharlesworth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of the VM, but if you do a heap dump of the Hotspot JVM you can see a special object for each class which holds the static fields.

You can access them dynamically at runtime by using reflection.